# Doubling one letter with each new occurence

Tags: java, string, character, letter

so I have task to double number of letter "a" every time it occurs in a string.
For example sentence "a cat walked on the road" , at the end must be "aa caaaat waaaaaaaalked on the roaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" . I had something like this on my mind but it doubles every charachter, not only "a".

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "a bear walked on the road";
    String result = "";
    int i = 0;
    while(i<s.length()){
        char a = s.charAt(i);
        result = result + a + a;
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check what the `char a` is (in your case, 'a'). Additionally, you do not repeat the characters more than twice in your code, hence not getting the answer you expected: `result = result + a + a` only adds 'a' twice, **not** giving you: "aa caaaat waaaaaaaalked...".

Here is the solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "a bear walked on the road";
    String result = "";
    char lookingFor = 'a'; // Can change this to whatever is needed
    int counter = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == lookingFor) { // The current character is what we need to be repeated.
            
            // Repeat the character as many times as counter is (each loop: 2, 4, 6, 8, ...)
            for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++) {
                result += lookingFor;
            }

            counter *= 2; // Double counter at every instance of 'a'
        }
        else { // The current char is not what we are looking for, so we just add it to our result.
            result += s.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problems are:

- you are doubling every character because you are not testing if it is an 'a' or not.
- and you are not doubling the substitution each time.

Here is a modified version of your solution.

```
String s = "a bear walked on the road";
String result = "";
String sub = "aa";
int i = 0;
while(i<s.length()){
    // get the character
    char ch = s.charAt(i++);
    //if it an a, append sub to result
    // and double sub.
    if (ch == 'a') {
          result +=  sub;
          sub += sub;
    } else {
        // otherwise, just append the character
        result += ch;
    }
}
```

Here is another way.

- check each character and double the replacement each time an `a` is encountered.

```
String str = "a cat walked on the road";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String sub = "a";
for (String s : str.split("")) {
    sb.append(s.equals("a") ? (sub += sub) : s);
}
        
System.out.println(sb);
```

prints

```
aa caaaat waaaaaaaalked on the roaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaad
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char letterToSearch = 'a'
    String myString = "a bear walked on the road";
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int occurrance = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++){
        char currChar = myString.charAt(i);
        if (currChar == letterToSearch){
            occurrance+=1;
            for (int j = 0; j < 2*occurrance; j++){
                result.append(currChar);
            }
        } else {
            result.append(currChar);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

The variable `occurrance` keeps track of how many `a`s you have.